# Indices not rotated in SPHINX

Tags: sql, sphinx

I want to use 2 indexes (querys), but sphinx gives this warning:

```
[sphinx@reea3 ~]$ /usr/bin/indexer --config /home/sphinx/sphinx/sphinx.conf --all --rotate
Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)
Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff

using config file '/home/sphinx/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'job1'...
collected 6 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 6 docs, 837 bytes
total 0.005 sec, 152988 bytes/sec, 1096.69 docs/sec
indexing index 'job2'...
collected 8 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 8 docs, 151 bytes
total 0.002 sec, 53794 bytes/sec, 2850.01 docs/sec
total 10 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.2 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 20 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.3 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
WARNING: failed to open pid_file '/var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid'.
WARNING: indices NOT rotated.
```

Below is the source code.
I have taken out the sql query and attribute list.

Whats to be done in order for SPHINX to rotate indices?

```
#
# Minimal Sphinx configuration sample (clean, simple, functional)
#

source jobSource1
{
    type        = mysql
    sql_host    = localhost
    sql_user    = root
#   sql_pass    = 123456
    sql_pass    =
    sql_db      = dbx
    sql_port    = 3306
    sql_query   = sql_query
    sql_attr_uint = attributes go here
    sql_attr_str2ordinal = attributes go here
}

source jobSource2
{
    type        = mysql
    sql_host    = localhost
    sql_user    = root
#   sql_pass    = 123456
    sql_pass    =
    sql_db      = dbx
    sql_port    = 3306
    sql_query   = sql_query
    sql_attr_uint = attribute
    sql_attr_str2ordinal = attribute
}

index job1
{
    source      = jobSource1
    path        = /home/sphinx/jobs/job1
    docinfo     = extern
    charset_type    = utf-8
}

index job2
{
    source      = jobSource2
    path        = /home/sphinx/jobs/job1
    docinfo     = extern
    charset_type    = utf-8
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit   = 32M
}


searchd
{
    port        = 9312
    log     = /var/log/sphinx/searchd.log
    query_log   = /var/log/sphinx/query.log
    read_timeout    = 5
    max_children    = 30
    pid_file    = /var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid
    max_matches = 1000
    seamless_rotate = 1
    preopen_indexes = 0
    unlink_old  = 1
}
```

Comment: Does that pid file '/var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid' exist? What are its permissions (is it readable by the user running the indexer)? 

Also, why are you running such an old version of Sphinx?

Comment: the searchd was started as root, the admin tooked care, now its working; this was the only sphinx compatible with what we have on the machines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, after a brainstorming seasion with my colleagues, we talked to the admins, and it turned out that the searchd process was initialized using the root priviledges, so only the root user could modify the file.

After restarting the process with the normal priviledges, everithing turned out to be working just fine;

Answer (score -1):

use this command `sudo indexer --rotate --all`

Comment: this command only for standart congif (/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf)